# Utilitários para o site e chat (tampermonkey/greasemonkey)

Tags: debate

Existem muitas coisas no site e chat que realmente por diversas limitações ainda não são possíveis, isso vale para qualquer site da rede, eu tinha a ideia de implementar tudo o que fosse possível em um add-on próprio, mas muitas coisas realmente podem ser mais fáceis se feitas usando o *Tampermonkey* e *Greasemonkey*.

### Como usar

- [Tutorial para tampermokey](http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php?ext=dhdg)
- [Tutorial para greasemonkey](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Installing_Scripts)

Se você não vai desenvolver mas veio procurar um script então primeiro instale o:

- [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) se for Firefox
- [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pt-BR) se for Chrome
- [tampermonkey](https://addons.opera.com/pt/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/?display=en) se for Opera

### Colaborando/Compartilhando

Se você tiver um script e quiser compartilhar, este é lugar, ele tem que atender todos estes requisitos:

1. Estar disponível publicamente, alguns exemplos que pode usar são o *http://github.com* ou *http://gist.github.com* (mas qualquer outro sistema semelhante é aceito)
2. Tem que ter o nome neste formato `xxxxx.user.js`, ou seja ficaria algo como `meuscript.user.js` (o `.user` facilita a instalação no tampermonkey e greasemonkey)
3. Uma descrição breve e se possível uma imagem que ilustre o funcionamento

Um exemplo de esboço (opcional):

```
## Titulo

Descrição

Fonte/Repositório: Link

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>][1]

----------

### Amostra

![descrição](url da imagem)


[1]: xxxxxxxx.user.js
```

Answer (score 12):

### ChatFullName

Este script exibe o nome completo no chat mesmo em mensagens simples, existem muitos usuários com o mesmo primeiro nome, isto pode confundir, mas com o sobrenome facilita, este script irá lhe ajudar nisto.

É possivel muitas vezes diferenciar pela foto, mas ocorre que alguns usuários como o caso do Diego (que eu conversei) tem alguns domínios bloqueados de onde acessam, como no caso do `*imgur.com`, que é o domínio que a *Stack Overflow* usa para armazenar as imagens.

- Repositório: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/ChatFullName.user.js

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/ChatFullName.user.js)

---

### Amostra:

- Sem script:

  [image: sem]
- Com script:

  [image: com]

Comment: Acho que o link do "Clique aqui para instalar diretamente" está trocado. Está referenciado para o `DevelopmentMode`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss corrigido ;)

Comment: +1 esse me é muito util, ainda mais quando se tem o imgur bloqueado e um chat cheio de duplicatas :p

Comment: Com ele nunca mais vou confundir vc com o outro guilherme :)

Answer (score 9):

### CleanChat

Muda o visual do chat

Fonte/Repositório: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/CleanChat.user.js

> Se instalar este "tema" não será necessário instalar o script ChatFullName, pois ele já faz isto "nativamente"

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/CleanChat.user.js)

---

#### Amostra

[image: chat]

Answer (score 8):

### Highlight (destaca postagens)

Quando você marca uma tag como favorita, a cor dela às vezes não funciona bem em alguns monitores, ou algumas pessoas que sofrem com [daltonismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daltonismo) têm dificuldade para enxergá-la, ou você simplesmente não gosta da cor, este script permite personalizar.

- Após instalado, você pode trocar a cor aqui pela que mais lhe agradar:

  ```
    var bgColor = '#FCA'; //Troque pela cor desejada
  ```
- Repositório: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/Highlight.user.js

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/Highlight.user.js)

### Amostra:

[image: Amostra]

Answer (score 7):

### DevelopmentMode (Para desenvolvedores Web)

Este script não tem muito a ver com a rede, mas como somos um site sobre programação então para quem desenvolve voltado para Web, este script pode ser útil. Ele adiciona para as URLs `http://localhost` e `http://127.0.0.1`:

- Prefixo da tag `<title>`.
- Uma "label" fixa no rodapé.

Após instalar, você pode alterar estas linhas para adicionar ou trocar as URLs:

```
// @match        *://localhost/*
// @match        *://127.0.0.1/*
```

Pode adicionar por exemplo:

```
// @match        *://localhost/*
// @match        *://127.0.0.1/*
// @match        *://192.168.*
// @match        *://10.*
// @match        *://dominio-de-homologacao.com/*
```

E altere aqui para customizar o texto do título e label:

```
var dmlabel = 'Desenvolvimento'; //Label que aparece no <title> e no div no rodapé
```

- Repositório: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/DevelopmentMode.user.js

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/DevelopmentMode.user.js)

---

### Amostra:

> [image: amostra]

Answer (score 7):

### SO ClearChat

Um script Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script com algumas funções úteis para o chat do StackOverflow.

Instalação: <kbd>[Instalar SO ClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat/raw/master/so-clearchat.user.js)</kbd>

Fonte: [github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat)

Este script adiciona 5 funcionalidades, três apresentadas como links abaixo do título da sala:

> [image: usage]

- **clear** - remove todas as mensagens;
- **remove media** - troca todas os vídeos e imagens por uma tag de texto:

> [image: remove messages with medias]

- **Thumbnails** de imagens marcadas com estrelas:

> [image: Thumbnails for starred images]

- **Modo Noturno**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionalmente o script permite o uso de shortcuts no chat:

- <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd>: Quote
- <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>: Strike-through
- <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>: Bold
- <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd>: Italic

Comment: Eu uso :D e aprovo!

Answer (score 5):

### CleanChat - WhatsApp

Utilizando [CleanChat](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/CleanChat.user.js), o CleanChat - WhatsApp do muda o visual do chat para um visual que lembra o WhatsApp.

#### Nova funcionalidade

Ao clicar no nome do usuário na barra lateral, ele referencia o mesmo no chat, adicionando o **@NomeUsuario** no `textarea`.

#### Amostra

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Fonte/Repositório: https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/CleanChat.user.js

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/CleanChat.user.js)

Comment: A barra de pesquisa aqui ficou deslocada, um pouco em cima do botão `site rooms` as frase estreladas tambem sumiram. Provavelmente deve ser pela resolução da tela(notebook 14" com 1366x768).

Answer (score 3):

### Bye Stars, Bye

Este script remove as mensagens com estrela de moderadores

Fonte/Repositório: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/ByeStars-Bye.user.js

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/ByeStars-Bye.user.js)

---

#### Amostra

[image: Com e sem estrelas de moderador]

Answer (score 3):

### SOptCommentContextMenu

Aciona todos os links Comentar na pergunta, e adiciona um Menu Contextual com comentários rápidos.

Fonte/Repositório: https://github.com/wellmotta/SOptCommentContextMenu

[<kbd>Clique aqui para instalar diretamente</kbd>](https://github.com/wellmotta/SOptCommentContextMenu/raw/master/SOptCommentContextMenu.user.js)

---

#### Amostra

[image: SOptCommentContextMenu.png]

Comment: Nossa!!! Show mesmo, cara parabéns, ainda não testei, mas a ideia é sensacional! Irei testar hoje, muito obrigado pela colaboração.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento creio que precise de muitos ajuste, ainda sou aprendiz aqui rs. Toda sugestões e criticas são bem-vindas.

Comment: Tem o [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) também. Tem algumas coisas que são semelhantes ao seu utilitário.

Comment: Esse ai não conhecia, assim que eu estiver em um computador vou ver, achava que no aqui no *SOpt* que tinha isso no meta, apesar que lá eu nem acesso, por ser leigo, poucas coisas entendo do Inglês porque as vezes usava o *Windows XP* em inglês e por causa de um *FPS* que jogava.

Comment: @Stormwind, é verdade, instalei ele aqui no navegador, cara a diferença é que aqui é *Menu Contextual*, e lá é *Modal*.

Comment: E que utiliza um JSONP para geração dos comentários. @WéllingthonM.deSouza

Answer (score 2):

## “View Vote totals” without 1000 rep

A extensão ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) te possibilita ver os votos de uma certa pergunta ou resposta de qualquer site da rede **sem que você tenha 1000 de reputação**, utilizando a API do StackExchange.

O pulo do gato é que você consegue ver os votos também nas **filas de análise**

[image]

que sem a extensão é impossível.

<kbd>[Instalar diretamente (.js)](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/code/Stack%20Exchange:%20%22View%20Vote%20totals%22%20without%201000%20rep.user.js)</kbd> <kbd>[Instalar como extensão do Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd)</kbd>