# O que é a estrela vazada no chat?

Tags: suporte, chat, proposta-para-faq

Estou acessando o chat e já faz alguns dias que eu vejo que tem uma publicação que está sempre no topo das estrelas recentes. É uma [publicação do @rray de 9 de fevereiro](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42770524#42770524).

[image: estrela vazada]

O que significa essa estrela vazada? Como uma fala ganha essa estrela vazada? Existem outras publicações marcadas com isso?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Essas estrelas são colocadas pelos mods para fixar um comentário ao topo dos favoritos.

Comment: **Nota:** Criei um script para greasemonkey e tampermonkey que pode ajudar quem não quiser ver estas estrelas de mods https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5855/3635

Comment: BTW, nós, carinhosamente, apelidamos elas de "estrelas sem alma".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "estrela vazada" indica que um moderador da sala que marcou aquela mensagem para fixa-la no mural do chat.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de adicionar uma imagem.